# Declaring WithEvents variables - Compilation error: invalid characteristics in Sub or Function"

Tags: vba, outlook

I have two sets of code. The first code adds a preset BCC address triggered by a button. The second code enables filing of emails, by tagging/categorizing the sent email, copying that sent email and then moving the copy to the folder indicated in pickfolder.

The two codes work separately.

When I paste both codes in ThisOutlookSession, the second one does not work. The error is (loosely translated from Dutch): "compilation error: invalid characteristics in Sub or Function" which relates to all three declarations (`Dim WithEvents objInspectors As Inspectors, Dim WithEvents objMyNewMail As MailItem, Dim WithEvents colSentItems As Items`)

The full codes:

```
'button bcc to crm system emailaddress)

Sub AddCRMtoBCC()
    Dim objRecip As Recipient
    Set oMsg = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    With oMsg
        Set objRecip = oMsg.Recipients.Add("__@__.com")
        objRecip.Type = olBCC
        objRecip.Resolve
    End With
    Set oMsg = Nothing
End Sub
'________


'file emails

Dim WithEvents objInspectors As Inspectors
Dim WithEvents objMyNewMail As MailItem
Dim WithEvents colSentItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInspectors = Application.Inspectors
    Dim NS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set NS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set colSentItems = NS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items
    Set NS = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Quit()
    Set objInspectors = Nothing
    Set objMyNewMail = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub objInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub
    Set objMyNewMail = Inspector.CurrentItem
End Sub

Private Sub objMyNewMail_Send(Cancel As Boolean)
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to send this message?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion _
        , "SEND CONFIRMATION") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub colSentItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        Set Copy = Item.Copy
        Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set objFolder = objNS.PickFolder
        Copy.Move objFolder
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ware you able to fix the issue?

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply. At first it did not, but after a fresh outlook install (for different reasons) it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you declare global variables at module level (`ThisOutlookSession` is a module), all of them should be declared at the top of the module.

thus, move those 3 lines at the top , before the very first `sub()`

```
Dim WithEvents objInspectors As Inspectors
Dim WithEvents objMyNewMail As MailItem
Dim WithEvents colSentItems As Items
```

Answer (score 0):

objMyNewMail_Send() Cancel parameter must be declared ByRef